# New site not showing in Google for unique name

Tags: google, seo, google-search-console

I have launched a site for myself and now I'm doing some simple SEO for it.

The site uses my name and it's unique and has no competition on search engines, but I don't know why Google crawlers haven't done anything on my site.

I have added my site's URL to Google (via addurl) and I have also signed in to Google Webmaster Tools.

The title and the url of my site is also related to my name, but even when I Google my name Google returns nothing about my site, and Google Webmaster Tools also shows no keywords for my site. Do you have any idea why this happens?

[update] OK, I won't link my site here, I launched it about 5 days ago, and it's on my name (completely unique). I just want it to be shown everytime some one Googles my name - just that simple, but it seems Google hasn't done anything with my site yet, is this normal?

Comment: how long ago did you launch your site. Is it a unique domain ? Oh yeah and yes, post a link to your site here with your post as well.

Comment: No, please **don't** include a link to your site. That's a quick and easy way to get your post flagged as spam. Stack Overflow is not an engine to promote your personal website. You've done the right thing by asking a generic question, useful to the broad audience of the Internet.

Answer (score 6):

If you launched your web site five days ago, I would say it is quite normal for you to find search engines have done nothing to your web site.

Submitting your web site to Google is only an attempt for you to make Google index your web site, but it does not necessarily mean Google will index your web site so quickly.

In your case, I suggest you to do two things immediately. First, put your links to some web sites which share the same segment of visitors so that your back links are relevance to your web site, like web sites about Car and and that of Tire share the same visitors. You can do this by adding comments on blogs and forums and so forth.

Another thing is take a look at your web site code. Some times one single piece of error may block Google to index your web site. Since you already have a Google web master tool account(Good job, it is a very good tool, do not forget to use Google Analytics as well.), do a "Fetch as a bot" test to see if everything is alright.

This may not important, but useful, be patient.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Comments on stackexchange questions won't be any use because they use `nofollow` tags to tell Google to ignore the links.

A few links from pretty much any reasonable quality site that's been around for a several years and get's updated often should lead to at least your homepage being placed in the index (as long as the link doesn't have the `rel="nofollow"` attribute. For example, you could try submitting the site to the technorati blog directory.

However, being in the index doesn't mean that Google will place you into the search results. If you are just looking to get queries on your name (an exact match on the domain name) to show up in the first page of results then the above links might be enough (as long as your name is relatively unique and doesn't show up in many other places on the web). If you actually want the keywords in your content to show up then you are likely to need links from pages that have a similar theme.

Answer (score 0):

Google needs to find a link to it from another page on the internet that it indexes ... You can create a profile here that would include a link by using the login button on the top of the page - answer some Qs and place it in the "Home Page" box here. Comment on a interesting blog post using your site in the "home page" box. If you have a twitter account (already indexed) tweet. A facebook account share link. A youtube account add it to your profile. Many forums allow signature lines to your site almost all forums have a place in your profile for your website.

It will take more than 5 days. The more links you have the faster it will send the robot to your site to index new pages and higher it will list you in the search results. However think quality not raw numbers of links.

Answer (score 0):

I would also make sure you're taking advantage of the meta tags that go in your ... for example:

```
<meta name="description" content="This is the personal website for My Name">
<meta name="keywords" content="My Name, Web Development, Awesomeness, etc...">
```

SEO on google is a tricky subject... whether it's due to the fabled 'sandbox effect' or what... You said you have no competition on the name so I won't go any further than saying it'll be tough if your name is 'John Smith'.

Another great reference that I send all my buddies to, though a little old, is a good start:

http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/SearchFriendlyDevelopment.html

Nice little vid there.  Hope that helps!

Good luck mate!

**EDIT:** @John Conde - his problem isn't page rank.  It's an issue with being identified.  Adding the tags may allow you to be recognized by the things you type in... now, if someone else wanted to use your name on their web page they have a chance to outrank you, but you'll at least be on the list.

Comment: Remember, meta tags do not affect ranking. That is well established and unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest things you can do is put some links on profiles in different places.

One trick is to use your linkedin profile and use other for the link type and choose your keyword as the title and the domain as the link.  This normally gets items indexed and ranking for people based domains very fast.